# InnoDB composite indexing order and INSERT performance

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, composite-index

I have a MySQL table with 3 columns on which I'd like to use a multi-column index. Column A is TINYINT, B is SMALLINT and C is VARBINARY (16). Should I use the index as A, B, C, because A has lower granularity than B and B lower than C to achieve maximum INSERT speed?

Answer (score 2):

(Note: This answer clarifies or disagrees with some of the comments already written.)

`DELETEs` are slowed down because of deleting the index entries. `UPDATEs` *may* be slowed down -- it depends on whether an indexed column is changed.

`SELECTs`, `UPDATEs`, and `DELETEs`, but not `INSERTs`, need to find the row(s); for this, an index may help a lot.

An `INSERT` is hurt an extra amount if there is a `UNIQUE` index to check.

Secondary keys (in InnoDB), *except* for `UNIQUE` keys, are updated (usually due to `INSERT` and `DELETE`, but possibly due to `UPDATE`) in a 'delayed' way via what is called the "Change Buffer".  This effectively puts off updating the index, but still keeps the index fully usable.

None of this is impacted by the order of the columns in an index.  However, if an index is bigger than can be cached in RAM, "caching" comes into play, and I/O may or may not be involved.  But that is another topic.

In general the *benefit* from an index for reading *far outweighs* the slowdown for write operations.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes actually **slow** data modification queries (insert, update, delete) down, since the rdbms has to change not only the table itself, but the index(es) as well.

From an insertion speed point of view, the order of fields in an index is not relevant, it is the number of indexes that matter.

Comment: Couldn't it be said that *Indexes can speed up some data modification queries (insert,update,delete)*?

Comment: In case of update and delete when the rdbms has to locate the record to be changed, then an index may speed up the location part and slow down the the change. However, in case of an insert, however, the rdbms does not have to locate any records.

Comment: I have some 2 and 3 digit million row tables that delete and update would be impossible for UX without indexes.

Comment: And what about insert?

Comment: Shadow, you seem to think indexes may get you data quicker. But maybe not. I would suggest you pound on huge datasets for a while. It gets very tiresome reading what people have feelings for about how things may work. It is rare people spend the time to prove it. That is pretty much what I do.

Comment: @Drew I pound on datasets eith several millions of records every day. That's my job. Inserts were only slowed down by indexes, deletes and updates were either slowed down or were unaffected.

Comment: So you never found an index to benefit anything versus a table scan. Then ditch your indexes I guess. I'll keep mine :p

Comment: [Indexes can promote fast updates and deletes](http://i.imgur.com/hBsalet.jpg). I'll take a tenth of a second over 25 seconds anytime.